# Polynomial fit need help printing the formula for the curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, formula, curve-fitting

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([(333, 195.3267), (500, 223.0235), (1000, 264.5914), (2000, 294.8728
), (5000, 328.3523), (10000, 345.4688)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

So this script creates a polynomial fit for the inserted data. I want to use the poly text feature or some feature in order to print the formula for the curve fit. I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: What did you try, and why did it not work?

Comment: Perhaps, `print(f)`?

Comment: @DavidG oh nice feature, I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidG Worked perfectly! So simple. Can I get the chi squared for this as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P
c, stats = P.polyfit(x,y,3,full=True)
```

Now you can get an array of coefficients by printing `c` and ssr stats!

The examples in the documentation are quite understandable! https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html

Comment: Why does this have a downvote? It looks like some mad and angry people are around who downvote everything. This answer provides information on how to get the chi squared, which was asked for by the OP in an comment. This deserves an upvote, since it is helpful!

Comment: @Scotty1 as soon as I published this answer it got a - 1 vote may be dur to less explanatory answer.. Don't know.. By the way thanks for your support :)

Comment: @Scotty1, are the downvotes you have observed Python-related only?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I'm only around in the section with python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas and numba, so yes. Satya: Yeah, your answer is less explanatory, but imho still a correct and helpful answer. Thus a downvote, is in my opinion, not ok. But it seems that some people consider only lengthy answers explaining all possibilities as good answers. I personally prefer answer that are short and come straight to the point.